# Python: Check has access to copy file from remote server

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to ask your help in the following: I have a Python code (use Python 3.8) where I collect some files from remote servers.
The scripts is working properly, only what I can not: how I can check, if I have access to copy file(s) from the remote server or not?
I am using SCPClient to connect to the target server and with the get method I copy file(s) from target to local.
If the copy is possible  and only in this case I would like to remove/delete the previous file(s).

My experiences: the get method do the copy if user has access to file and/or able to copy given file(s), but it is "late" for me, to delete file(s). So before run the get function in SCPClient, I would like check it the copy process will be fine or not.

I check that that file is exists or not on the remote server, but currently that's all. If file exists, I call SCPClient.get() method, but in some case it run onto error: do not have permissions to copy file :(
I did not find any "dry" get() run or any other methods, which check access to the file and check that the scp copy is possible or not.
Is there any way for it?

Thanks!